# Syntax for bounded type parameters in Bifunction signature

Tags: java

Want to update this BiFunction to use bounded type parameters instead of upper bounded wildcard args. Need help with the syntax. Thanks.

```
public static final BiFunction<
         Map<? extends Identifier, Map<DateTimeRange, Usage>>,
         Map<Period, DateTimeRange>,
         Map<Period, Map<? extends Identifier, Map<DateTimeRange, Usage>>>
> periodFilter = (usageMap, timeRangeMap) -> 

                  // do something ;
```

Comment: So what's stopping you from using `? extends`? --- BTW: Your naming violates Java naming conventions, which state that class and interface names should start with uppercase letter, so your types should be named `Identifier`, `Usage`, and `Period`.

Comment: The current signature is working fine. I'm just trying to use type variables T, S, etc so that i can avoid some casting in the caller. Is it not supported (i'm new to the world of generics)?

Comment: @Andreas thanks for noticing. Edits made.

Comment: Where did you envision `T` and `S` would get bound, i.e. resolved to actual types? It's a static field, so there is no context to bind them. To allow binding, you need a method.

Comment: Can't we do the binding using `apply()` method of Bifunction? Basically, what i'm trying to do is if i pass 2 params (T extends Identifier, S extends Usage), this BiFunction should be able to refer to it and reuse the same types in the return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the two wildcards to be bound to the same actual type, that means you want `<K extends Identifier>` and this signature:

```
BiFunction<
     Map<K, Map<DateTimeRange, Usage>>,
     Map<Period, DateTimeRange>,
     Map<Period, Map<K, Map<DateTimeRange, Usage>>>
>
```

To do that, you need a static method to return a bound type, where `K` is resolved to an actual type, not a single static instance.

```
public static <K extends Identifier> BiFunction<
            Map<K, Map<DateTimeRange, Usage>>,
            Map<Period, DateTimeRange>,
            Map<Period, Map<K, Map<DateTimeRange, Usage>>>
        > getPeriodFilter() {
    return (usageMap, timeRangeMap) -> /* do something */;
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
Map<Identifier1, Map<DateTimeRange, Usage>> t = /* ... */;
Map<Period, DateTimeRange> u = /* ... */;

BiFunction<Map<Identifier1, Map<DateTimeRange, Usage>>,
           Map<Period, DateTimeRange>,
           Map<Period, Map<Identifier1, Map<DateTimeRange, Usage>>>
           > filter = getPeriodFilter();
Map<Period, Map<Identifier1, Map<DateTimeRange, Usage>>> r = filter.apply(t, u);
```

The inference engine cannot resolve `K` if you try `getPeriodFilter().apply(t, u)`, so you have to explicitly give it, which means you have to qualify it with class name:

```
Map<Period, Map<Identifier1, Map<DateTimeRange, Usage>>> r =
        MyClass.<Identifier1>getPeriodFilter().apply(t, u);
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. This makes a lot of sense.